# Proof of inequality $|x \sin \alpha + y \cos \alpha| \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, radicals, absolute-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Just like in the title, I'm asking for any hints for proving (propably simple) inequality:

$$ |x \sin \alpha + y \cos \alpha| \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Hint: Assuming $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$, we can divide both sides by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ can be thought of as $\sin \beta$, in which case $\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ will be....?

Comment: @AnuragA Of course, thanks! Should be obvious for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By C-S $$|x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha|\leq\sqrt{(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity,

$$(x\cos t+y\sin t)^2+(x\sin t-y\cos t)^2=?$$